# In a Hotwire/Rails app, when to use target: '_top' for a turbo_frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, hotwire-rails, turbo

The turbo handbook explains `target: '_top'`  [here](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/handbook/frames#targeting-navigation-into-or-out-of-a-frame) and [here](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/reference/frames#frame-that-drives-navigation-to-replace-whole-page).

But I still don't understand what's the difference between these two forms:

#1

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'new_search', target: '_top' do %>    
  <%= search_form_for :q do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#2

```
<%= search_form_for :q do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Both form will send a normal HTML format request via GET method, and the whole page will be replaced by Turbo Drive. So their behavior looks quite similar in this case.

Is `target: '_top'` only useful when I need to lazy load something via the `src` attribute of Turbo Frame while I want the content navigate outside the frame? :

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'something', src: '/something', target: '_top' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that a form outside of any wrapping frame (like your #2 example) is the same as a form within a frame tag that has a `target="_top"`

But consider your first example without the _top attribute:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'new_search' do %>    
     <%= search_form_for :q do |f| %>
     ...
     <% end %>
<% end %
```

This is now not the same as example #2, the result of the search form will only operate within the new_search frame. This is the point of the _top attribute, to break a form or link outside of it's wrapping frame.

Comment: Thank you! But when do I need to break the form outside of its frame?
I mean I can just remove the frame in my code.
And if I want to make specific link in the frame to navigate outside, I can use `data-turbo-frame="_top"` on the link. So I don't see a good case to add `target="_top"` to a frame.

Comment: You might be correct that it only makes sense when it's lazy loaded with src. Hotwire is still very new and the docs could be lacking, I recommended asking on their community page https://discuss.hotwire.dev/

Comment: in another word "_top" is target whole page?